# Can I use return value of INSERT…RETURNING in a SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to extract the `name` which is generated from an trigger function in postgres.
It generated after insert meaning when I do

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(....) RETURNING id,name
```

I only get the `id` and not the name, since the trigger only have generate the id, and not the name in the insert statement.

The `name` is generated by a trigger `AFTER INSERT`.

I can though extract the name using a select statement as such

```
SELECT name from registration_table where id = ANY(id)
```

how do nest these two queries together?
how do I pass the `id` property to the next query?

Comment: What about just returning everything?  `insert into table values () returing *`

Comment: returning will return name as nothing, as the trigger that creates the name is executed after an insert. @Hambone

Comment: Your INSERT does return both `id` and `name` - are you saying that the name gets generate later and you get NULL back? If so, when does it get generated and by whom?

Comment: @ShayRojansky it gets generated by a trigger, which is being triggered after `INSERT`

Comment: Create the name before the INSERT and you can use RETURNING id, name;

Comment: the `name` is a combination of the column values for the particular row, that has being inserted, which is why I have a trigger which after the `INSERT` generates the name, and insert it into the row. @FrankHeikens

Comment: You can do that with a before insert trigger, or a generated column which is simpler.

Comment: Before insert assume the values are in the row, which they are not.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to wrap the INSERT and the SELECT in a single function, and call that.